# managing and linking hierarchical data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-modeling

So in my application database I have a business profile entity that has:

- one main **Category** (e.g. Restaurant, Hotel, Hospital, ...etc)
- unlimited **Subcategories** (e.g. pizza restaurant, Italian restaurant, ...etc)
- unlimited **products** (e.g. cheese pizza, pepperoni pizza, ...etc)
- unlimited **services** (e.g. pick-up service, delivery service, ...etc)

*P.S. I went with the Restaurant category as an example to demonstration its subcategories/services/products entities, but, it could be any anything really.*

**First:** I can use something like the **Adjacency List Model** to define unlimited categories and their corresponding subcategories but, what about **services** and **products** entities ? how can I link them all to each another knowing that **services** and **products** are children of the **subcategory** entity?

For now this is what I have: 
[Figure-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxahv.png)

**Second:** How can I map each **Business profile** with its **Category/subcategories/products/services** ?! so that I know each business profile is under what category and what are the subcategories/products/services that each business profile has.

Here is the mapping that I have at the moment:
[Figure-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC7ZM.png)

I am yet a novice database designer, I'm trying to make this database to be as much efficient as possible, as it will receive a lot of traffic. Is what I have now valid as a database scheme or is there any database designing concepts that needs to be dig deeper?

Comment: This may fit better on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @TypeIA, I am still new to the platform, could you please tell me why do you think that [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) platform and its community fits my question better?

Comment: Because that site is specifically [geared for database administration, (advanced) querying, and schema design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and this site is not (it is [about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). There is admittedly some overlap.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @TypeIA :))

Answer (score 0):

When I read this question I was worried this was going to have a complicated tree structure, but reading your work so far it's very clean and simple.

Personally, I think you're on the right track, and would make a few notes:

- It's not hard to link services and products to subcategories, and you can also easily link businesses and products/services. I don't think this needs to be a tree. Just enforce this restriction when the records are created.
- Adjacency List Model makes a lot of sense for trees of arbitrary depth for which you need to easily find subtrees, but I'm not sure if that fits your problem, in particular because:

  1. You don't have arbitrary depth. You just have parents and sub-categories.
  2. For something like a business-category system, the number of entries might be low enough that it's not worth adding the extra complexity. It's probably pretty fast to read the entire table and keep it in memory.

If you want services and products linked to both subcategories and categories, the simplest might be to have a single category table and have each category have a `parent_id` that may be null.

Comment: thank you Sir! it is good to know that I am on the right track :). I have two questions though: 1) could you please clarify what do you mean by: *Just enforce this restriction when the records are created*?. 2) do you really think that *Figure-2* is good and does not need to be approached in a different way

Comment: @jes I guess that was confusing, but what I meant was that your data model might not need to reflect that businesses can only be associated with products/services that belong to categories the business also has. This can be an application-level constraint. I agree mostly with Figure-2, except you _might_ want to combine categories and sub-categories depending on your requirements.